# How to add and show images in a WPF TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, treeview, bitmapimage

I fill a TreeView (WPF) in the code and want to use some icons in the items.
I can load and add BitmapImage but it is only displayed, when the BitmapImage is also assigned to another ImageControl in the window (and shown there):

```
TreeViewItem newItem = new TreeViewItem();
Image tempImage = new Image();
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Resources/ok-01.png", UriKind.Relative));
tempImage.Source = bitmapImage;

imageControlInWindow.Source = bitmapImage; //if I delete this line (it is not needed) the image in the TreeViewItem is not shown

TextBlock tempTextBlock = new TextBlock();            
tempTextBlock.Inlines.Add(tempImage);
tempTextBlock.Inlines.Add("SomeText");
newItem.Header = tempTextBlock;
```

How can I force the image to be shown in the TreeView without the hack of showing it outside the treeview as copy?

Comment: Why don't build up data templates for treeview items?

Comment: How about `InvalidateVisual`

Comment: The image file should have its Build Action set to Resource. It would then be loaded by a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly): `new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/ok-01.png")`.

Comment: Thanks Clemens ... that worked :-) Want to add this as correct answer?

Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not loading the image files from a proper [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly).

It should look like this:

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/ok-01.png"));
```

The Build Action of the image file must be set to **Resource**.

Answer (score 1):

MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="TreeViewTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}" />
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Stretch="Uniform" Height="30"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public List<MyItem> Items { get; private set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Items = new List<MyItem>
        {
            new MyItem {Text = "Item 1", ImageSource = "/image1.png"},
            new MyItem {Text = "Item 2", ImageSource = "/image2.png"}
        };
    }
}

public class MyItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string ImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Surely in a treeview the image normally belongs to the left of the tree item? It makes a really ugly UI having it after the text.