# Not able to make bindings in treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

Im trying to make a custom treeview with an itemtemplate, so I can show the headertext + a type of the item in the treeview.

My inspiration comes from this answer;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33119107/9156219

So, my problem is that I cant make the Itembindings work.
Here's my code;

XAML:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding treeList}" Grid.Column="0" IsVisibleChanged="treeView_IsVisibleChanged" SelectedItemChanged="treeView_SelectedItemChanged">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" Margin="2,2,2,2" Background="LightBlue" FontSize='8'/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SystemName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

C#

```
    public class CustomTreeViewItem : TreeViewItem
    {
        public String SystemName { get; set; }
        public String Type { get; set; }
        public String ParentItem { get; set; }
        public String Path { get; set; }
    }

    public List<CustomTreeViewItem> treeList = new List<CustomTreeViewItem>();

    public void SetRootNode()
    {
        int itmNumber = datSet.Rows.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < itmNumber; i++)
        {
            treeList.Add(new CustomTreeViewItem
            {
                SystemName = (string)datSet.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString(),
                Type = (string)datSet.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString(),
                ParentItem = (string)datSet.Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString(),
                Path = (string)datSet.Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString(),
            });
            treeList[i].Header = treeList[i].SystemName;
        }


        foreach (CustomTreeViewItem item in treeList.Where(treeList => treeList.ParentItem == ""))
        {
            treeView.Items.Add(item);
        }

        foreach (CustomTreeViewItem item in treeList.Where(treeList => treeList.ParentItem != "").Where(treeList => treeList.Type != "Signal"))
        {
            var test = treeList.Find(treeList => treeList.SystemName == item.ParentItem);
            test.Items.Add(item);
        }

    }
```

SetRootNode() is being called in the beginning of the program. datSet is being filled with a OleDBDataAdapter.

In the treeview, only the SystemName is being showed and not the type. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a TreeView whose TreeViewItems contain yet again TreeViewItems, if you remove the inheritance for your model, it works:

do this:

```
public class CustomTreeViewItem
```

instead of

```
public class CustomTreeViewItem : TreeViewItem
```

is this good enough for your needs?

Comment: Yay, it's working!

However, now I can't add child items. The following paragraph can't be executed, because CustomTreeViewItem no longer inherits from TreeViewItem.

`            foreach (CustomTreeViewItem item in treeList.Where(treeList => treeList.ParentItem != "").Where(treeList => treeList.Type != "Signal"))
            {
                var test = treeList.Find(treeList => treeList.SystemName == item.ParentItem);
                
                test.Items.Add(item);
            }`

Comment: https://testdrivendevelopment.wordpress.com/2008/07/15/databinding-wpf-treeview-using-recursion/ is one simple way to do it

Comment: You need to look for a way that backs your tree view with proper view model, instead of trying to hack into TreeViewItems. This may sound like an offhanded comment but unless one embraces the MVVM properly there will be no end to the troubles with TreeView. For instance, read [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode)